# Need to create a link to call a function in a module

Tags: hooks

Want to create a link "Click Here To..." that will call a function in a module.

What is the best way to achieve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one way to skin a drupal.  What is "best" depends heavily on the situation, but here are a few options.  Is this drupal 8 or drupal 7?

Use rules instead of functions, and the [Rules Link](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_link) module.

Use a hook_menu to make a [menu_local_tasks](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/constant/MENU_LOCAL_TASK/7) (a.k.a. tab) and style it how you want.

Look at the [print](https://www.drupal.org/project/print) module for inspiration and use a [hook_node_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7) to add to the node's normal link set, where print adds it's print links.

As I have said on the irc many times, give more context information to get a better answer.

Comment: Thanks here is some more input - I am using the LinkedIn module and want to call the linkedin_access_token when someone is on a specific but dynamic page (ud/%uid) and clicks on a link that says Authorize.